# why my custom control textbox's onpaint overided method never gets called?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, user-controls

I have created a customized textbox which has border in red color. I then launch my application but this OnPaint never gets called.

My code is this:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : TextBox
    {
        public string disable, disableFlag;
        public string Disable 
        { 
            get 
            { 

                return disable;
            } 
            set 
            { 
                disable = value;
                disableFlag = disable;
                //OnPaint(PaintEventArgs.Empty);
            } 
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            this.Text = "testing 1";
            if (disable == "true")
            {

                Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
                Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
                graphics.DrawRectangle(redPen, this.Location.X,
                              this.Location.Y, this.Width, this.Height);
                //  base.DrawFrame(e.Graphics);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know what is the problem (Here is the snapshot of the winform http://prntscr.com/ceq7x5 )?

Comment: There's no point adding a custom Disable flag. Use the Enabled property that is already provided by the Windows Forms TextBox control.

Comment: Yes you are right , I am doing it for some other purpose.. please ignore it.

Comment: _Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();_ This is __almost always__ wrong and trying to owner-draw a TextBox is __always__ wrong. It will not work. Sorry. TextBox is legacy and won't let you draw anything persistent on it, even if you did it right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new Graphics object. Use `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle` to be able to draw on the control using the already existing Graphics object like this:

```
Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(redPen, this.Location.X,
                          this.Location.Y, this.Width, this.Height);
```

Also, to repeat my comment here about the Disabled flag. There's no point adding a custom Disable flag. Use the [Enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property that is already provided by the Windows Forms TextBox control.

**Edit:** Please notice that the above code doesn't work in TextBox's case, because it handles drawing differently. TextBox is basically just a wrapper around the native Win32 TextBox so you need to listen to quite a few messages that tell it to repaint itself. You also need to get the handle to the device context and transform it to a managed Graphics object to be able to draw.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Controls/ListBox_and_ComboBox/TextBox_Icon/article.html) for code and explanations on how to draw on top of TextBox. Especially part *2. Drawing Onto the TextBox* on the bottom of the page.

Comment: None of those invokes the OnPaint method i am overriding on launching my code.

Comment: Actually, I need to update my question. TextBox is a tricky control because of the way it handles painting. Wait a minute.